# Verb "to have" used in present tense

Tags: negation, present-tense, do-support

Which one of these two is a correct sentence?

> I have not a computer.
>   I do not have a computer.

I am confused, the book I am reading  has the first sentence but the second one sounds right.  Please explain the reason of correct sentence.

Comment: As a stand-alone sentence, 'I have not a computer.' is probably better described as 'non-standard' rather than 'rarefied'.  Using it in any normal environment would identify the speaker as a complete eccentric or a learner. / Main verbs (and have = possess is a main verb) use do-support for negation as in your second sentence (though 'BrE' doesn't need do-support for the interrogative: 'Have you an atlas you could lend me?')

Comment: "Have" (in the sense "possess") when used without _do_ support, is an auxiliary verb.

Comment: Although "I have no computer." is standard usage.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that both sentences are correct, but the first is archaic and so is less common in today's world.